# Why are the Big O Notations for the following codes like this?

Tags: big-o

#### Question 1.

My Answer: 1 + n^2 * n = n^3

Correct Answer: O(n)

```
void f(int n) {
    if (n<1000000)
         return 0;
    for (int i=0; i<(n*n); i++)
         return f(n-1);
}
```

#### Question 2.

My Answer: n * n * logn = n^2*logn

Correct Answer: O(n^3)

```
int f(int n) {
    for (int i=1; i< (n/2); i++) 
        for(double j =0; j <100; j+= (100.0/n) 
              doSomething (n/2); //doSomething(m) has time complexity of O(m)
    return 0;
}
```

#### Question 3.

My Answer: 1 + n * (logn + 1) = O(nlogn)

Correct Answer: O(logn)

```
int f(n) {
    if (n<1) return;
    g(n-1); 
}

void g(n) {
    f(n/2) 
    doOne(); // doOne has time complexity O(1)
}
```

Comment: Question 1 is a trick-question because the `for` loop will execute a `return` immediately after the recursive function-call - and that recursive call-chain is the `O(n)` component, *not* the `for` loop.

Comment: I get it thanks @Dai

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Question 1

> ```
> void f(int n) {
>     if (n<1000000)
>          return 0;
>     for (int i=0; i<(n*n); i++)
>          return f(n-1);
> }
> ```

The `for` loop is not looping at all because the content is a `return` statement, so you have at most **one** loop iteration. This means you can can simplify this code to:

```
void f(int n) {
    if (n<=0)
         return 0;
    return f(n-1);
}
```

*(simplified in regard for the O(n) analysis)*

Here you see why it is `O(n)` because it is counting down until it hit the recursion stop condition. The fact that there is a "high" value check for `n<100000` doesn't matter when you call it with something like `f(5*10^300);`

### Question 2

> ```
> int f(int n) {
>     for (int i=1; i< (n/2); i++) 
>         for(double j =0; j <100; j+= (100.0/n) 
>               doSomething (n/2); //doSomething(m) has time complexity of O(m)
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

In regard for the `O(n)` analysis you can simplify some lines:

```
for (int i=1; i< (n/2); i++)
```

This can be simplified to:

```
for (int i=1; i<n; i++)
```

Therefore it's `O(n)` as already identified by you.

```
for(double j =0; j <100; j+= (100.0/n)
```

This can be simplified as:

```
for(double j =0; j <1; j+= (1.0/n)    (divided by 100)
for(double j =0; j <n; j+= 1.0)       (multiplied by n)
```

And again, a simple `O(n)` loop.

```
doSomething (n/2);
```

That is by definition a `O(n)` statement.

So in total you have `O(n)*O(n)*O(n)`, which is `O(n^3)`.

### Question 3

> ```
> int f(n) {
>     if (n<1) return;
>     g(n-1); 
> }
>
> void g(n) {
>     f(n/2) 
>     doOne(); // doOne has time complexity O(1)
> }
> ```

Not sure how you got the `O(n*log(n))` here because not every `n` value is checked. In fact you start at `n` and the steps are `n/2`, `n/4`, `n/8`, `n/16`, `n/32`, `n/64`, `n/128`, ... and at some point you reached the terminate condition `if (n<1)`. This is a simple `O(log(n))` loop.

Comment: I liked the brief explanation.